# getchar function skipped the first character when used after integer

Tags: c++, string, char, getchar

Hello everyone this problem made me crazy 
i have to take large line as input T number of times. I use following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int T;
    char buffer,b1;
    cin >> T>> b1;
    //fflush(stdin);

    while(T--)
    {
        char ch,c;
        int A[14];
       while((ch=getchar())!='\n')
       {
           cout << ch;
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know if we taken input character after integer then it store null as a character thats why i take an extra input as b1(as a buffer) so that null will store in it.
when i pass input as

```
2
758
8758
```

It gives following output

```
58
8758
```

Comment: You have a few problems with the code you show. First of all [`std::getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/getchar) returns an `int`. This is important when you check for `EOF`, which leads to the second problem: You don't check for end-of-file or errors. There's also a potential third problem, but you commented it out: Doing `fflush` on an input-only stream is *undefined* in the C and C++ specifications.

Comment: replace cin >> T>> b1; with cin >> T; no need to read null value as you said.

Comment: Furthermore, why are you using `getchar` in a loop to read character by character? Is this a school exercise or something? What is the actual problem you attempt to solve?

Comment: As i said input is very large i can't store it in string and traverse it.

Comment: 1) Put `#include <cstdio>`.  2) `cin >> T>> b1;` --> `cin >> T;
 cin.ignore();`

Comment: When you say "very large" what do you mean by that? Hundreds of bytes? Thousands? Several kilobytes? Megabytes? More? The code as you show it doesn't really make much sense without more context.

Comment: If i replace cin >> T>> b1; with cin >> T then it will skip one test cases as in first case it store null in put. I have to traverse all characters i can't store it in string

Comment: use `cin.get(ch)` to read characters not getchar http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get

Comment: thanks BLUEPIXY it works and @Someprogrammerdude it have 10^(100000) characters

Comment: @Sudhir Tiwar so it has  10^99877 **times** more characters than our Universe has atoms. Great

Comment: yep @PeterJ_01 question says that u can check in codechef challenge

Answer (score 0):

As BLUPIXY suggested in comments replace

```
cin >> T>> b1;
```

with

```
cin >> T; cin.ignore();
```

It works